# Autoincrement, but omit existing values in the column

Tags: postgresql, sequence, auto-increment, unique-constraint, gaps-and-islands

I have a table:

```
create table DB.t1 (id  SERIAL,name varchar(255));
```

and insert some data:

```
insert into DB.t1 (name) values ('name1');
insert into DB.t1 (id,name) values (5,'name2');
insert into DB.t1 (name) values ('name3');
insert into DB.t1 (name) values ('name4');
insert into DB.t1 (name) values ('name5');
insert into DB.t1 (name) values ('name6');
insert into DB.t1 (name) values ('name7');
select * from DB.t1;
```

Then I can see:

```
1 name1
5 name2
2 name3
3 name4
4 name5
5 name6   -- how to make auto-increment jump over '5'?
6 name7
```

But 5 is present two times. How to keep `id` unique?

Comment: Are you sure, you really need this?

Comment: Define `id` as the primary key, and you can't insert the same value twice.

Comment: [This recent related question on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60802/fixing-table-structure-to-avoid-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-cons/60807) may be of help. Generally: don't insert values manually into a serial column.

Comment: I need such solution. customer wants to get rid from ASA database and wants to copy its data to psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@erwin-brandstetter
Won't it be faster to first find the missing value and then simply `setval('t1_id_seq'::regclass, )`, thus removing excessive `nextval` calls? 
Also, if the question is how to make *ids* unique, assigning this code for *default value* won't solve the problem.

I'd suggest using *unique* constraint or *primary key* constraint and handle *unique violation* exception.

Comment: This answer should be a comment, but Stack Overflow has annoying restrictions on that for new users. Anyway: your proposed approach isn't safe in the face of concurrent inserts, because what your transaction sees as "free" might've already been allocated to another uncommitted transaction. (I agree that just handing a unique violation might be cleaner).

Comment: I think this has enough substance to pass as answer in its own right. What you write is the standard procedure for excluding dupes. There was also the question `how to make auto-increment jump over '5'?` And that's what my answer does. It should perform well with few islands and many gaps (which seems to be the case according to the example). To *enforce* uniqueness, add a constraint.

Answer (score 7):

Update: Later, more detailed answer:

- [Make Postgres choose the next minimal available id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152523/make-postgres-choose-the-next-minimal-available-id/28154950#28154950)

---

This should work smoothly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_next_free(_seq regclass)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      PERFORM nextval(_seq);
      EXIT WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM db.t1 WHERE id = lastval());
   END LOOP; 

   RETURN lastval();
END
$func$;
```

Loop fetching the next number from a given sequence until one is found that is not yet in the table. Should even be **safe for concurrent use**, since we still rely on a sequence.

Use this function in the column default of the `serial` column (replacing the default for the serial columns `nextval('t1_id_seq'::regclass)`:

```
ALTER TABLE db.t1 ALTER COLUMN id
SET DEFAULT f_next_free('t1_id_seq'::regclass);
```

[The manual on `lastval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

This performs well with few islands and many gaps (which seems to be the case according to the example). To *enforce* uniqueness, add a [unique constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) (or primary key) on the column.

Comment: Huh. Nice. It's not going to be gapless, since a row ID lost by rollback won't be re-used, but it's concurrency safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a trigger function on inserting. This function will chck if NEW.id is not null and update the sequence related to the id field.

```
IF NEW.id IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT SETVAL(sequence_name_of_id_field,NEW.id);
END IF;
```

Comment: What keeps me from entering a row with `id = 10`, and later `id = 8`?

Comment: Then, you must use a trigger function instead of a sequence. When inserts a row, if id is null, search the max id of table and assign the id of new inserted row.

Comment: Trigger +`max()` isn't concurrency safe. You'd have to `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` first. And no, you can't do that within the trigger, you'll get frequent deadlocks due to lock upgrades.