# Make PostgreSQL choose the next minimal available id

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, gaps-and-islands

I would like to make PostgreSQL choose **the first next available id** so that no error occurs in the following case:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar
);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2,'dd');
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('aa');
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('bb');
```

This will give a constraint error since `id` is primary.
How can I tell PostgreSQL to insert the record with the next free id?

Comment: you don't need to tell it to choose. It will do automatically. Just suppress the id information. Of course, if the primary is serial. Postgresql will create a sequence to it

Comment: @Jorge: I think OP already has out-of-order ID's in their database and wants to know how to fix things...

Comment: You shouldn't be providing manual values for a serial column. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: I understand, but in my scenario:     the user can either specify an id he wishes        or he doesn't specify an id

Comment: Take out the responsability of the user in controlling the ID.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the test setup. `"Test"` and `Test` would have been referring to *different* tables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, it's best to *never* overrule the default in a `serial` column. If you sometimes *need* to provide id values manually, replace the standard `DEFAULT` clause `nextval('sequence_name')` of the `serial` column with a custom function that omits existing values.

Based on this dummy table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test_test_id_seq(OUT nextfree bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT INTO nextfree  val
      FROM   nextval('test_test_id_seq'::regclass) val  -- use actual name of sequence
      WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM test WHERE test_id = val);

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP; 
END
$func$;
```

Use it in column default:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN test_id SET DEFAULT f_test_test_id_seq();
```

It's not strictly a `serial` any more, but `serial` is only a convenience feature anyway:

- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

And if you build this on top of a `serial` column the `SEQUENCE` is automatically "owned" by the table column, which is probably a good thing.

This is a slightly faster variant of:

- [Autoincrement, but omit existing values in the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407444/autoincrement-but-omit-existing-values-in-the-column/22411460#22411460)

And it's equally safe against conflicts under concurrent write load.

**Table and sequence name are hard coded** here. You *could* easily parametrize the sequence name (like in the linked answer) and even the table name - and test existence with a dynamic statement using `EXECUTE`. Would give you a **generic function**, but the call would be a bit more expensive.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_nextfree(_tbl regclass
                                     , _col text
                                     , _seq regclass
                                     , OUT nextfree bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      EXECUTE '
      SELECT val FROM nextval($1) val WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM ' || _tbl || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(_col) || ' = val)'
      INTO  nextfree
      USING _seq;

      EXIT WHEN nextfree IS NOT NULL;
   END LOOP; 
END
$func$;
```

Use it in column default:

```
ALTER TABLE test2 ALTER COLUMN test2_id
SET DEFAULT f_nextfree('test2', 'test2_id', 'test2_test2_id_seq');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M69R_Wc5)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/196c3)</sub>